# Implement Fact++ reasoner in OWLAPI5

Tags: ontology, owl-api, reasoner, fact++

How can I add Fact++ reasoner in my OWLAPI5 Application?
I added Fact++ dependency in pom.xml but when I run, I received this Exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" uk.ac.manchester.cs.factplusplus.FaCTPlusPlusException:
    org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.ReasonerInternalException: Can't get class for Pointer
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.factplusplus.FaCTPlusPlus.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Thank you very much for every suggestions,
Rita

Comment: I'm not sure if FaCT++ is compatible with OWLAPI 5. Its Java module seems to require OWLAPI 4.

Comment: Most of the owlapi code is the class FaCTPlusPlusReasoner.java,  If you import the java code in your editor (Eclipse) most of conversion work will be done automatically. In the end it work fine.